# is there a way to check if all apps are up to date without google play in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

I'm working on app that needs also to check if all apps are up to date without Google Play.

is there a way to do it ?

those android phones doesn't have Google Play.

thank you

Comment: Apps are updated through Google Play. This is kinda like asking how to go to Google without the internet. We may be able to find an answer, what phone specifically doesn't have Google Play?

Comment: it is a Jewish Kosher android phones. the User needs to delete Google play from the phone. the only way to install apps is to get the apk. my question is if there is an Api or WS where i can go and check if all apps are up to date

Comment: Google Play services is is the API. You could go with Amazon's AppStore though. Is it a kosher thing to delete Google?

Comment: lol, if the Rabbi says it's Kosher so it is Kosher i think.

Comment: Here's a [description of how play services works](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html). I don't see a way to access it without the play services APK.

Comment: ok, so i have another question. can i set Google play app as invisible?

Comment: Do you have root access? I believe play services can be installed with the Play Store being installed. Would need to research.